# Sticky Menu Change Logo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on website, which have a sticky menu, What i need to do is change the logo when its scroll and have sticky header.

And header is like that

```
<header id="header" class="float-panel" data-top="0" data-scroll="100">
```

once i scroll down , class changes to fixed

```
<header id="header" class="float-panel  fixed" data-top="0" data-scroll="100">
```

and i need to change logo once its going to fixed either with css or jquery , i am enable to target , i tried using following

```
if($("#header.float-panel").hasClass('fixed'))
```

Here is the logo div

```
<div class="logo"><!-- logo -->



    <a href="http://"><img src="Logo-Full_Pos.png" alt=""></a><h6 class="site-title"><a href="http://.com/" rel="home">g</a></h6>                           
                            </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: No need for script, just use in CSS `.float-panel.fixed { .... }`. You can put your logo as bg-image, or use 2 elements, which change `display: block` to `display: none`.

Comment: Not sure how to do this , can you help please ?

Comment: I tried to put two logos, so i can play one hide and one show but failed

Comment: Use `.float-panel .logo1{display: block} .float-panel.fixed .logo1{display: none} .float-panel .logo2{display: none} .float-panel.fixed .logo2{display: block}` got it?

Comment: Its worked , Thanks alot !

Answer (score 3):

This line of code: if($("#header.float-panel").hasClass('fixed')) will only be run onload. You'll need to use the scroll event: https://api.jquery.com/scroll/ to ensure your if statement is hit when the menu becomes fixed.